# Unauthorised access to folders when creating xml file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, exception, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm working on a WPF application where the user sets the target path for an xml file to be created, but I'm always getting an UnauthorizedAccessException, even if the target directory is in my own computer.
I've already tried replacing `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` with `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` in the app.manifest file to force the program to run as administrator but it didn't work either.
The exception message I get is

> Access to the path [path] is denied

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Where does [path] generally point to? Do you still get the error when path = C:\Temp ?

Comment: @BerndLinde This path is a directory chosen by the user, can be in the local machine or on the network.
I tried following your suggestion but I still got that exception

Comment: Please then show how you are creating the xml file, since in a general directory like C:\Temp anyone should have write access

Comment: The file may be in use.

Comment: I appreciate your comments guys, but I found an alternative solution to this issue, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for this issue was to create a folder inside the target directory set by the user with the following code:

`DirectoryInfo info = Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);`

Then, set the program to create the xml file inside that newly created folder.